# How to create referral system on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

**Iam as an admin role, i want to create a referral system in my apps.**

Eg. i have 3 users, user A, user B and user C

user B and user C use Referral code from user A.

and i want to create a list that show user B and user C name as referrals in user A's view.

in users table : `:user_id,  :referred_by` (FYI i use user_id as a referral code)

in users/show

```
<%= link_to @user.referred_by, user_path(@user.referred_by) %>
```

(I put user_id as referred_by in form)

Inside user B/C profile, this code display the id of referrer(user A)

But i dont know how to display a list of referrals (user B and user C) in user A profile

can u explain step by step? I am very confused about the logic.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get all of the users referred by the current `@user`

`@referals = User.where(referred_by: @user.id)`

With that in the controller, you can then iterate over the `@referals` object as a list of users with this in your view

```
<ul>
@referals.each do |referred_user|
    <li><%= referred_user.id %></li>
end
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering. I put the code inside user.controllers and i put @referals inside the show but the code show this #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fddd1d2a580>

Comment: I updated the answer with the code you'd want in the view. That will display a list of the referred users IDs - you can change that attribute from `id` to `name` or whatever you want to display.

Comment: 1 more question sir, in my users controller i put referals = User.where(referred_by: user.id), and in my show views i put Referred By : <%= link_to user.referred_by, user_path(user.referred_by) %>. it display ID of the referrer. how can i display email instead? thanks

Comment: `<%= link_to user.referred_by.email, user_path(user.referred_by) %>` should do it. You can treat the referred_by object as if it was a User object, so it will have all of the attributes any User object would.